# Finding the exact value of the sine of the angle between a line and a plane

Tags: vectors, cross-product, angle

[image: The question about finding the exact value of the sine of the angle between (PQ) and the plane]

I have done part (a). For part (b), I know the principle of how to do it, I tried to use the cross product to find the exact value of the sine of the angle.

So I found PQ which is $$\begin{pmatrix}7-2\\-1-1\\2-6\end{pmatrix}$$

$$=\begin{pmatrix}5\\-2\\-4\end{pmatrix}$$

Then I do the cross product between $$\begin{pmatrix}5\\-2\\-4\end{pmatrix}$$ and $$\begin{pmatrix}5\\-3\\-1\end{pmatrix}$$ which the normal vector for the plane equation given

and using $$||{\bf a} \times {\bf b}|| = ||{\bf a}|| \, ||{\bf b}|| \sin \theta,$$ I got the answer to be $\sqrt (490)/\sqrt (490)$ which makes $sin\theta =1$ but the answer states that  $sin\theta = \sqrt 7/3$. Where did I go wrong?

Thank you and sorry in advance for any wrong tags and title labelling.

Comment: Please check calculations

Comment: I checked it 3 times @ArchisWelankar, which part did I go wrong? the cross product?

Comment: The determinant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the determinant is $-10i+15j-5k$ so its $\sqrt{350}$ and rhs is $\sqrt{45\times 35}.sin\theta=\sqrt{1575}.sin\theta$ so $$\sqrt{\frac{350}{1575}}=sin\theta$$ solving you get $sin(\theta)=\sqrt{7}/3$. Thats all

Answer (score 1):

Use the scalar product to find the cosine of the angle between $PQ$ and the normal. The angle between the line and the plane is $90 -$ this, so the sine of the required angle is the same as the cosine you obtain from the scalar product. You don't need to use cross product at all.

Comment: Why to run away from vector product

Comment: You can use vector product if you want, but you will obtain the sine of the angle between the plane normal and PQ. You would then have the cosine of the required angle, so you would have to calculate the sine of that...

Comment: We want sine not cosine

Comment: I know, but the angle between the line PQ and the normal is the complementary angle to the angle between the line PQ and the plane.

Answer (score 1):

The angle angle between line $PQ$: $(5, -2, -4)$  & the normal  to the plane:$(5, -3, -1)$ is given by using dot product as $$\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{(5, -2, -4)\cdot (5, -3, -1)}{|5, -2, -4||5, -3, -1|}\right)=\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{35}{\sqrt {45}\sqrt{35}}\right)=\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt 7}{3}\right)$$
hence the angle between plane & the line $PQ$ $$\theta=\frac{\pi}{2}-\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt 7}{3}\right)$$$$=\color{red}{\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt 7}{3}\right)}$$
or $$\sin\theta=\frac{\sqrt7}{3}$$

Answer (score 1):

You are using **cross** product instead of **dot/scalar** product. It should be:

$$ a . b = ||a||~||b|| sin \theta $$

$$ sin\theta = \frac{a.b}{||a||~||b||} = cos\alpha $$

$\theta$ is the angle between the line PQ and the plane.
$\alpha$ is the angle between the line PQ and the normal to the plane, (5,-3,-1).

$$ sin\theta = \frac{(5,-2,-4).(5,-3,-1)}{||(5,-2,-4)||.||(5,-3,-1)||} $$

$$ = \frac{35}{\sqrt{45} ~.~ \sqrt{35}} $$

$$ = \frac{7~.~5}{\sqrt{9}\sqrt{5} ~.~ \sqrt{7}\sqrt{5}} $$

$$ \implies sin\theta = \sqrt{7}/3 $$